# How to validate whether runas command succeeded or not?

Tags: javascript, runas, testcomplete

I am trying to launch an application with a specific user using runas command. I want to know whether the command is success or not. In manual scenario after entering the password, if I use echo %errorlevel% it returns 0 for successful execution or else 1. But How can I capture the same in Jscript so that I can determine whether my command is success or not. Pls help.

I am using JScript with Testcomplete tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your application to TestedApps, set its Run Mode to *RunAs* and enter the credentials in the Parameters. Then use the following code:

```
var p = TestedApps.MyApp.Run(); // replace MyApp with the name of your app in the Project Explorer
if (! p.Exists) {
  // runas failed
}
```

As an alternative to configuring *RunAs* parameters in the IDE, you can specify them directly in your script code:

```
var p = TestedApps.MyApp.RunAs("domain", "user", "password");
if (! p.Exists) {
  // runas failed
}
```

BTW, if you are using Windows Vista or Windows 7, make sure to run TestComplete as Administrator in order for this to work.

Comment: Thanks Helen.. I am using this one. Just want to know is there any way directly thru Jscript? But I think this one is a more appropriate solution. btw.. It is TestedApp.Runas()

Comment: @svv: There're both `Run` and `RunAs`; they are slightly different. You use `Run` when you have specified the runas credentials in the IDE, and you use `RunAs` to pass them via your script code.